# Extract number of rows from fread without reading the whole file

Tags: r, windows, data.table

I have a large text file (475,000,000 lines). I would like to quickly get the number of rows in the file without reading it.

`fread` from `data.table` actually comes up with the row number quite rapidly (~10 seconds) before it proceeds to read the whole file:

```
fread('D:/text_file.txt',select=1,colClasses="character")
Read 7.1% of 472933221 rows #number of rows appears after 10 seconds
```

Is there a way to extract this row number without reading the whole file afterwards? For the record, reading the whole file takes 36 seconds.

I have tried `countLines` from `R.utils` but it takes 53 seconds. The difference might be that `fread` has an option to select only one column and countLines reads everything.

```
R.utils::countLines("D:/text_file.txt") #53 seconds
```

I have also tried other Windows methods such as:

```
find /v /c "" "D:\text_file.txt" #takes 1 minute 50 seconds
grep "^" D:\text_file.txt | wc -l #takes 2 minutes
```

These work, but they're not as fast as `fread`. I'm on Windows.

Comment: Try `wc -l filename` found in Windows Rtools.

Comment: Did you try to write a small function in C? It's very easy and should be fast.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you works like a charm. This takes 8 seconds to run: `shell('wc.exe -l "D:/text_file.txt"',intern =TRUE)`

Comment: @d.b I added an answer to explain how I have access to `wc` on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

@d.b asked me to provide a detailed answer to my own question. As @G. Grothendieck suggested, the answer is to use `wc`, which is part of [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), a collection of resources for building packages for R under Microsoft Windows.

Once installed, make sure `C:\Rtools\bin` is in your `PATH` in environment variables in Windows.

Then, `wc` becomes available to R using `system` or `shell`:

```
shell('wc -l "D:/text_file.txt"',intern =TRUE)
```